# get total hours worked in a day javascript without using any library

Tags: javascript, css, html

Well, I'm new on this page and excuse me if my English is ugly but I do what I can do to communicate myself :)
I am doing a page that can calculate the total hours worked in a day and this is what I got until 15/06/17
[my page](http://www.kignkoa.altervista.org/casa/paginas/somma%20di%20ore.html)
**note:** the language used in my page is Italian, sorry for that.

**giorno = day**

My problem is that I can't solve the function of the button called "Calcola"
this is what I got: (i don't know how to write code here so please see the code on "my page" using the Google tool)

the problem is at the end called:

```
function differenza()  
{       
       problem...   
}
```

I hope this has been clear, repeat sorry for my English I'm improving it.

Comment: first of all you have made your script as a comment using /* js code */
second, to make it easier, use 24h format of time.
third. using only one <input> for both hours and minutes should be better, with a simple script, you can make it add ' : '  after the 2 first numbers are written(if you write for example 12, it will automatically add :    meaning it will become 12:      thus leaving you space to add the minutes). Applying this to enter time and exit time would make it easier to calculate it.

Comment: thanks i'm going to try that

Comment: `var time = document.getElementsByClassName('time'); //Get all elements with class "time"
for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) { //Loop trough elements
    time[i].addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {; //Add event listener to every element
        var reg = /[0-9]/;
        if (this.value.length == 2 && reg.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value + ":"; //Add colon if string length > 2 and string is a number
        if (this.value.length > 5) this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1); //Delete the last digit if string length > 5
    });
};`

Comment: the above code is the code to add    :    after 2 first characters, ive used it on my own projects so i know it works, just play around with class names, or u can use get.elementbyid instead of classname that i have used. hope it helps

Comment: @masterNixe can you post it as an answer? Comments aren't meant for answers.

Comment: @Ian this is not an answer. i just gave him a few directives on how to achieve what he needed, if i wrote the code to do what he wants, then it would be an answer.

Comment: @masterNixe thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@masterNixe thanks everyone i did it look at this and please
[Try it](https://jsfiddle.net/9eydhbLw/)

it is a little bit different to your example @masterNixe but thanks :D
here is my page to [try](http://www.kignkoa.altervista.org/casa/paginas/somma%20di%20ore.html)
if someone find a bug please tell me

```
<script>
    function differenzaTotale() {
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < document.getElementById("tabella").rows.length; i++) {
            /*if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataMinuti").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataMinuti").value = "00";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaMinuti").value == ""){
                document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaMinuti").value = "00";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataOra").value == ""){
                document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataOra").value = "00";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaOra").value == ""){
                document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaOra").value = "00";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "PausaMinuti").value == ""){
                document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "PausaMinuti").value = "00";
            }*/
            differenzaRiga(i);
        }
    }

    function differenzaRiga(i) {

        var risultato = primoControllo(i);
        if (risultato == false){
            return false;
        }

        /* calcolo */
        var minDiUscita = risultato.minDiUscita;
        var minDiEntrata = risultato.minDiEntrata;
        var minDiPausa = risultato.minDiPausa;
        /*console.log(minDiUscita + '-'+ minDiEntrata +'-'+ minDiPausa);*/
        var differenzaInMin = minDiUscita - minDiEntrata - minDiPausa;
        var oreFatte = Math.floor(differenzaInMin / 60);
        var minutiFatti = differenzaInMin % 60;
        /*console.log(minDiUscita);
        console.log(minDiEntrata);
        console.log(minDiPausa);
        console.log(differenzaInMin);
        console.log(oreFatte);
        console.log(minutiFatti);*/
        document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "Totale").value = (pad(oreFatte) + ":" + pad(minutiFatti));
    }

    function pad(n) { // funzione che mi aiuta a sistemare i numeri prima dello zero mettendogli uno 0 davvanti es: 7:5 -> 07:05  NON HA CHE VEDERE CON IL CALCOLO è SOLO ESTETICA
        return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
    }
    document.getElementById('body').onkeypress = function (e) {//funzione che mi acceta l'invio come schiacciatoredi bottone
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        /*console.log(keyCode);*/
        if (keyCode == '13') {
            differenzaTotale();
        }
    }

    function primoControllo(i) {
        if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataOra").value == "") {
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaOra").value == "") {
            return false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaMinuti").value == "") {
            var minutiUscita = 0;
        }
        else {
            var minutiUscita = parseInt(document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaMinuti").value);
        }
        if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataMinuti").value == "") {
            var minutiEntrata = 0;
        }
        else {
            var minutiEntrata = parseInt(document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataMinuti").value);
        }
        if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "PausaMinuti").value == "") {
            var minutiPausa = 0;
        }
        else {
            var minutiPausa = parseInt(document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "PausaMinuti").value);
        }
        if (document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "PausaMinuti").value > "60") {
            document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "PausaMinuti").value = "60";
            var minutiPausa = 60;
        }
        var minDiUscita = document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "UscitaOra").value * 60 + minutiUscita; // math -> 16*60 + 20
        var minDiEntrata = document.getElementById("Giorno" + i + "EntrataOra").value * 60 + minutiEntrata; // math -> 7*60 + 30
        var minDiPausa = minutiPausa; // 45
        if (minDiUscita < minDiEntrata) {
            window.alert("ATTENZIONE: le ore di entrata sono maggiori a quelle di uscita");
            return false;
        }
        if (minDiUscita == minDiEntrata) {
            window.alert("ATTENZIONE: le ore di entrata sono uguali a quelle di uscita");
            return false;
        }

        var risultato = {

            minDiUscita: minDiUscita,
            minDiEntrata: minDiEntrata,
            minDiPausa: minDiPausa
        };

        return risultato;
    }
</script>
```